# How do I restrict phonegap application access to registered users only?

Tags: android, cordova

I'm developing a mobile application using Phonegap and I've created a working registration and login form through the use of PHP and JSON. However, I can't find anything online about how to restrict access to my application until a user either registers / logs in.

Anyone know the best way to do this please?

Thanks lots